# CRM 2011 LINQ Update Error

Tags: linq, dynamics-crm-2011

I am having trouble with CRM 2011 finding a record with LINQ and then updating the found record.  Even this super simple version won't work.  There error is totally generic (see below).

Here's the code, I do get a entity back from the query, I just can't update it.

```
var account = orgContext.CreateQuery("account").First(c => c["name"] == "apple");

account["name"] = "Microsoft";

orgContext.UpdateObject(account);
orgContext.SaveChanges();  ///ERROR HERE




ERROR DETAIL

Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.SaveChangesException was unhandled by user code
  Message=An error occured while processing this request.
  Source=Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk
  StackTrace:
       at Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Client.OrganizationServiceContext.SaveChanges(SaveChangesOptions options)
       at Dhs.Tsa.Trip.Xrm.Plugins.ProcessNFL.Execute(IServiceProvider serviceProvider) in C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\Dhs.Tsa.Trip.Xrm\Dhs.Tsa.Trip.Xrm.Plugins\ProcessNFL.cs:line 54
       at Microsoft.Crm.Extensibility.V5PluginProxyStep.ExecuteInternal(PipelineExecutionContext context)
       at Microsoft.Crm.Extensibility.VersionedPluginProxyStepBase.Execute(PipelineExecutionContext context)
  InnerException: System.ServiceModel.FaultException<Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.OrganizationServiceFault>
       Message=System.InvalidOperationException: Microsoft Dynamics CRM has experienced an error. Reference number for administrators or support: #97345966
       Source=Microsoft.Crm.Extensibility
       StackTrace:
            at Microsoft.Crm.Extensibility.OrganizationSdkServiceInternal.Execute(OrganizationRequest request, CorrelationToken correlationToken, CallerOriginToken callerOriginToken, WebServiceType serviceType)
            at Microsoft.Crm.Extensibility.InprocessServiceProxy.ExecuteCore(OrganizationRequest request)
            at Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Client.OrganizationServiceContext.Execute(OrganizationRequest request)
            at Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Client.OrganizationServiceContext.SaveChange(OrganizationRequest request, IList`1 results)
       InnerException:
```

Comment: Have you tried using `account.name = "Microsoft";`  ?

Comment: Can you post the rest of the exception details? It cuts out at ''Inner Exception' - is there not more detail to be added there?

Comment: [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/madenwal/archive/2011/03/22/crm-2011-sdk-error-while-using-the-create-method-system-argumentnullexception-value-cannot-be-null.aspx) may be relevant

Answer (score 1):

I'm not 100% sure what that error refers to, but I know in the past I've had problems trying to update with the same object as retrieved.  For example, if the object you fetch has missing required fields, it might not like you trying to save it back again.

Anyway, the solution is simple.  Rather than...

```
account["name"] = "Microsoft";

orgContext.UpdateObject(account);
orgContext.SaveChanges();
```

Try doing...

```
var updAccount = new Entity("account") { Id = account.Id };
updAccount["name"] = "Microsoft";

orgContext.UpdateObject(updAccount);
orgContext.SaveChanges();
```

This effectively creates a copy of the account reference with only the fields you want to update in it.